# Nestjs mongoose nested relationship

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs, relationship

I'm usign **nestjs** with **mongodb** and i'm having somw difficulties nested relationship inside Object
I have this kind of document stored in my db

```
{
   "_id": {
       "$oid": "6263d033c77035b3b8474b13"
   },
 "plannedTrip": [{
       "date": {
           "$date": "2022-04-13T19:53:00.834Z"
       },
       "location": {
           "$oid": "6261b43815788cddf30c7351"
       }
   }]    
}
```

and i have created this entity in nestjs

```
export type PlanTripDocument = PlanTrip & Document;

@Schema()
export class PlanTrip {
    @Prop()
    @Transform(({ value }) => value.toString())
    id: MongooseSchema.Types.ObjectId

    @Prop({type: [PlannedTripSchema]})
    plannedTrip: [PlannedTrip]
}

export const PlanTripSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(PlanTrip);
```

and this is the "PlannedTrip"

```
export type PlannedTripDocument = PlannedTrip & Document;

export class PlannedTrip {
    @Prop()
    date: Date
    
    @Prop({ type: MongooseSchema.Types.ObjectId, ref: Location.name })
    @Type(() => Location)
    location: Location
}

export const PlannedTripSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(PlannedTrip);
```

so in the service when i do

```
return await this.PlanTripnModel.find().populate('plannedTrip')
```

i expect to get back something like this:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "626332c990f43c292de0bcd4",
        "plannedTrip": [
            {
                "date": "2022-04-13T19:53:00.834Z",
                "location": {
                    "_id": "6261b43815788cddf30c7351",
                    "name": "nome",
                   "__v": 0
                }
            }
        ],
       
        "__v": 0,
    }
]
```

instead i'm getting this

```
[
    {
        "_id": "626332c990f43c292de0bcd4",
        "plannedTrip": [
            {
                "date": "2022-04-13T19:53:00.834Z",
                "location": "6261b43815788cddf30c7351"
            }
        ],
        "__v": 0,
    }
]
```

can you give me some suggestions, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to specify relation to another model, later for populating, the property should have type and ref.

So, in your 'PlanTrip' class, you should change 'plannedTrip' property to this:

```
  @Prop({ type: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'PlannedTrip' }] })
  plannedTrip: PlannedTrip[];
```

Comment: thank you for the reply, i tried your solution but i have a little problem, when i do a a get request, it returns all the keys but "plannedTrip" it's not even in the return document, i checked the db and there is "plannedTrip", how is this possible? How can i solve it?